# Concatenate a string and a boolean in C++?

Tags: c++, string, char, boolean, concatenation

I'd like to do something like the following:

```
bool b = ...
string s = "Value of bool is: " + b ? "f" : "d";
```

All of the examples I've seen use `cout`, but I don't want to print the string; just store it.

How do I do it? If possible, I'd like one example that assigns to a `char *` and one to a `std::string`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<strike>If your compiler is new enough, it should have [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string):</strike>

```
string s = "Value of bool is: " + std::to_string(b);
```

This would of course append `"1"` (for `true`) or `"0"` (for `false`) to your string, not `"f"` or `"d"` as you want. The reason being that ther is no overload of `std::to_string` that takes a `bool` type, so the compiler converts it to an integer value.

You can of course do it in two step, first declare the string then append the value:

```
string s = "Value of bool is: ";
s += b ? "f" : "d";
```

Or do it almost like you do now, but explicitly create the second as a `std::string`:

```
string s = "Value of bool is: " + std::string(b ? "f" : "d");
```

**Edit:** How to get a `char` pointer from a `std::string`

This is done with the [`std::string::c_str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) method. But as noted by Pete Becker you have to be careful how you use this pointer, as it points to data inside the string object. If the object is destroyed so is the data, and the pointer, if saved, will now be invalid.

Comment: What about assigning to a `char *`? I'm trying to call a function that requires it in the method signature.

Comment: @asdf4lyfe call `c_str()` on the string and it'll give you a `const char*`

Comment: Thanks! @Joachim-Pileborg, if you could edit that into the answer that would be good.

Comment: @Peter - right, but watch out for lifetime issues. The returned char* points to memory inside the string object, and it goes away if the string object is modified or destroyed.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream):

```
std::ostringstream s;
s << "Value of bool is: " << b;
std::string str(s.str());
```

and you can use [`std::boolalpha`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha) to have `"true"` or `"false"` instead of an `int` representation:

```
s << std::boolalpha << "Value of bool is: " << b;
```

---

Note the posted code is almost correct (it is not possible to `+` two `char[]`):

```
std::string s = std::string("Value of bool is: ") + (b ? "t" : "f");
```

---

To assign to a `char[]` you could use `snprintf()`:

```
char buf[1024];
std::snprintf(buf, 1024, "Value of bool is: %c", b ? 't' : 'f');
```

or just `std::string::c_str()`.

Answer (score 5):

Simple enough:

```
std::string s = std::string("Value of bool is: ") + (b ? "f" : "d");
```

Answer (score 3):

Encapsulate:

```
std::string toString(const bool value)
{
    return value ? "true" : "false";
}
```

Then:

```
std::string text = "Value of bool is: " + toString(b);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `std::stringstream`:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << s << (b ? "f" : "d");
std::string resulting_string = ss.str();
```

[stringstream reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/)

Answer (score 2):

Perform the operation in two steps:

```
bool b = ...
string s = "Value of bool is: ";
s+= b ? "f" : "d";
```

this is necessary because otherwise you would be trying to sum two `const char *`, which is not permitted; this way, instead, you rely on the overload of `+=` operator for `std::string` and C strings.

Answer (score 2):

Be simple:

```
bool b = ...
string s = "Value of bool is: ";
if (b)
  s += "f";
else
  s += "d";
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use strcat() as well

```
char s[80];
strcpy(s, "Value of bool is ");
strcat(s, b?"f":"d");
```

Answer (score 0):

For this simple use case, just append one string to the other:

```
std::string text = std::string("Value of bool is: ").append( value? "true" : "false" );
```

Now, for a more generic solution you can create a string builder class:

```
class make_string {
   std::ostringstream st;
   template <typename T>
   make_string& operator()( T const & v ) {
       st << v;
   }
   operator std::string() {
       return st.str();
   }
};
```

Which can be easily extended to support manipulators (adding a couple of extra overloads), but this would suffice for most basic uses. Then use it as:

```
std::string msg = make_string() << "Value of bool is " << (value?"true":"false");
```

(Again, in this particular case it is overkill, but if you want to compose a more complex string this would be helpful).